# Python: Solving memory constraints p‌r‌o‌b‌l‌e‌m in python online compiler?

Tags: python, algorithm, memory

**Problem**

I was solving this problem on Hackerearth, when submitted my code the Input 3
took 1045 MB memory and failed(memory constraint 25MB), for other inputs code just worked. I am trying to understand this behaviour but not getting it (nearly all input similar it got stuck on input 3). what's wrong in the code or what I missed?

**Question**

Chandan gave his son a cube with side N. The N X N X N cube is made up of small 1 X 1 X 1 cubes.

Chandan's son is extremely notorious just like him. So he dropped the cube inside a tank filled with Coke. The cube got totally immersed in that tank. His son was somehow able to take out the cube from the tank. But sooner his son realized that the cube had gone all dirty because of the coke. Since Chandan did not like dirty stuffs so his son decided to scrap off all the smaller cubes that got dirty in the process. A cube that had coke on any one of its six faces was considered to be dirty and scrapped off. After completing this cumbersome part his son decided to calculate volume of the scrapped off material. Since Chandan's son is weak in maths he is unable to do it alone.

Help him in calculating the required volume.

**My_Solution**

```
side_of_cube = list()
test_case = int(raw_input())
for i in range(test_case):
    side_of_cube.append(int(raw_input()))
    if side_of_cube[i] < 2:
        print 1
    else:
        volume = (((side_of_cube[i])**3) - ((side_of_cube[i]) - 2)**3) 
        print volume
```

**Input_provided**

Input 1

[Input 2](https://he-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/media/hackathon/algorithms-qualifiers-round-2/problems/d6e09e08-b-input-d6e099f.txt?Signature=7MmZYU3hpONQyRhf9foMLdhYj7A%3D&Expires=1455880668&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJLE6MUHDYS3HN6YQ)

[Input 3](https://he-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/media/hackathon/algorithms-qualifiers-round-2/problems/d75be702-b-input-d75be28.txt?Signature=3rDJj4J1N6pNnIZUoIsxlllEqzs%3D&Expires=1455880668&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJLE6MUHDYS3HN6YQ)

Input 4

Input 5

Comment: You need to use some maths, not brute force. Why do you need to cube such large numbers if you're then going to take them away? Why does the computer have to subtract two enormous numbers to give you a relatively small number. You need to think about the maths involved instead of pushing it all into the computer. You have a single layer of cubes, 6 faces of the main cube, you can work it out by adding 6 rectangle areas.

Comment: Thanks for the hint i changed those diff of cube into (a-b)*(a**2+b**2+a*b) form and it worked, memory taken under 64kb.but i don't understand how it make such a diff 64kb and 1045 mb. there's not a big difference in formula's though.

Comment: Are you telling us the whole story ? This code should consume very little memory. (It is not even necessary to store the side values.)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see input pages, but suppose that they could contain big numbers and `N^3` is too long.

But you can simplify the formula to quadratic result (or obtain the number of surface cubes in direct way using area, edges, corners)

I hope that this clue is enough to get better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Know your maths. You're looking for the difference of two cubes, so you have a simple factorization:

> a³-b³ = (a-b)*(a² + b² + ab)

In your problem, `a` is the side of cube, `b` is the side of cube minus 2, so it gets simplified to:

> a³-b³ = (a-(a-2))*(a² + (a-2)² + a*(a-2))
>   a³-b³ = 6*a² - 8*a + 8

And your code becomes:

```
side_of_cube = list()
test_case = int(raw_input())
for i in range(test_case):
    side_of_cube.append(int(raw_input()))
    a = side_of_cube[i]
    if a < 2:
        print 1
    else:
        volume = 6*(a**2) - 8*a + 8 
        print volume
```